# PHP - Create multiple arrays based on value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$r = array();
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test', 'supplierId' => 34];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test2', 'supplierId' => 31];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test3', 'supplierId' => 32];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test4', 'supplierId' => 34];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test5', 'supplierId' => 30];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test6', 'supplierId' => 32];
```

Now I want to take $r and get multiple arrays back, differenced by supplierId. So I am looking for this result:

```
    $r30 = ['name' => 'Test5', 'supplierId' => 30];
    $r32 = [
    ['name' => 'Test3', 'supplierId' => 32],
    ['name' => 'Test6', 'supplierId' => 32]
    ];
```

I tried it with, but here I do not have access to $sup in array_filter.

```
$supplier = array(30, 31, 32, 34);
$finalArray = [];

foreach ($supplier as $sup) {
    $finalArray[] = array_filter($r, function($value, $sup) {
        echo $sup;
        if ($value['supplierId'] == $sup) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}//foreach
```

Any idea how I can solve it? Is there no native function that accomplishes this - something like `create_array_based_on('supplierId');`?

Thanks

Comment: Would `$r30 = [['name' => 'Test5', 'supplierId' => 30]];` be suitable?

Comment: Yep, it would be @AlexBlex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `$sup` to your anonymous function:

```
foreach ($supplier as $sup) {
    $finalArray[] = array_filter($r, function($value) use ($sup) {
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ you need to pass
                                                                 it like this
        echo $sup;
        if ($value['supplierId'] == $sup) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}//foreach
```

But personally I would probably just loop over the original array and use the supplier ID as a key.

Something like:

```
$results = [];
foreach ($r as $value) {
    $results[$value['supplierId']][] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
$r = array();
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test', 'supplierId' => 34];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test2', 'supplierId' => 31];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test3', 'supplierId' => 32];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test4', 'supplierId' => 34];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test5', 'supplierId' => 30];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test6', 'supplierId' => 32];

$supplier = array(30, 31, 32, 34);
$finalArray = [];


$i=0;
foreach ($supplier as $sup) {
    $value =$r[$i]['supplierId'];
    if($value==$sup)
    {
        $finalArray[] = $value;
    }

 $i++;

}//foreach
```

$finalArray is a new array with all values you need

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) as following:

```
$finalArray[] = array_filter($r, function($value) use ($supplier) {
    return in_array($value['supplierId'], $supplier);
});
```

Without `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier, instead of wanting new variables for each of them, like $r32, $r35, etc... if you just used the array keys to store the supplierid, e.g.

```
$r = array();
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test', 'supplierId' => 34];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test2', 'supplierId' => 31];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test3', 'supplierId' => 32];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test4', 'supplierId' => 34];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test5', 'supplierId' => 30];
$r[] = ['name' => 'Test6', 'supplierId' => 32];

$newArray = array();

foreach($r as $key => $element)
{
    if (!isset($newArray[$element['supplierId']])){
        $newArray[$element['supplierId']] = array();
    }
    $newArray[$element['supplierId']][] = $element;
}
```

That would give you an output of:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [34] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test
                    [supplierId] => 34
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test4
                    [supplierId] => 34
                )

        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test2
                    [supplierId] => 31
                )

        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test3
                    [supplierId] => 32
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test6
                    [supplierId] => 32
                )

        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test5
                    [supplierId] => 30
                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about simple grouping nested arrays by some key value:

```
$finalArr = [];
foreach ($r as $arr) {
    $finalArr[$arr['supplierId']][] = $arr;
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

[***DEMO link***](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b485a53fb3c32982cba1e47d32e84e3f7d9a4247)